# I am missing you already

Tags: word-meaning

> Alice: I'm missing you already. Transcript: I'm missing you already. Clip duration: 12 seconds
> Source:  [Resident Evil](https://clip.cafe/resident-evil-2002/im-missing-already/)

How to define "miss" here?  Does "miss" here mean "regret the loss of 'good you' in the past"?

Comment: I have had to reformat your posts many times. Please try and put your quoted text in [blockquotes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression is almost an idiom, perhaps a cliché.

"I miss you" means "I am sad because you are not here"

"I'm missing you already" is sometimes said *as someone is leaving* as a way of saying "goodbye".

Literally, it means "I'm already sad because you are leaving, even though you only started to leave seconds ago". It is hyperbolic: the speaker is not really sad. Idiomatically it means "goodbye" but as a cliché it should usually be avoided.

Answer (score -3):

The word "missing" is defined (according to Dictionary.com) as:

> absent, not found, or lost

or:

> lacking

Obviously Alice is absent here but the statement has more meaning than simply that.

In the context of the source you shared, however, there is a slightly different meaning since it's used in the sense of a relationship, usually a close personal one.

The speaker or writer is telling Alice that he feels an emotional or even physical loss or distress at her absence from him.

Comment: "Missing" in "I'm missing you" is a verb (part of the "present progressive" or "present continuous" construction). It's not an adjective. The definition "absent" is irrelevant here.